# scss: compass, gruntjs and bower install foundation - import path

Tags: sass

So I have the following directory structure created by yeoman.

```
calvin % tree -L 2
.
├── Gruntfile.js
├── app
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── bower_components
|   |      └── foundation
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── robots.txt
│   ├── scripts
│   ├── styles
|   |      ├── main.css
|   |      └── main.scss     
│   └── views
├── bower.json
├── karma-e2e.conf.js
├── karma.conf.js
├── node_modules
│   ├── connect-livereload
│   ├── grunt
│   ├── grunt-concurrent
│   ├── grunt-contrib-clean
│   ├── grunt-contrib-coffee
│   ├── grunt-contrib-compass
│   ├── grunt-contrib-concat
│   ├── grunt-contrib-connect
│   ├── grunt-contrib-copy
│   ├── grunt-contrib-cssmin
│   ├── grunt-contrib-htmlmin
│   ├── grunt-contrib-imagemin
│   ├── grunt-contrib-jshint
│   ├── grunt-contrib-uglify
│   ├── grunt-contrib-watch
│   ├── grunt-google-cdn
│   ├── grunt-karma
│   ├── grunt-ngmin
│   ├── grunt-open
│   ├── grunt-rev
│   ├── grunt-usemin
│   └── matchdep
├── package.json
└── test
    ├── runner.html
    └── spec
```

In my styles directory, I have a `main.scss` file which is watched by compass, as configured in Gruntjs.

After I have installed foundation, via `bower install foundation` and my foundation files get downloaded into the `bower_components` directory, how do I import my foundation classes in `main.scss` ?

This doesn't seem to work

```
@import "foundation";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading up more, @Andrey's full solution is actually elaborated here - http://ericdfields.com/post/installing-compass-frameworks-in-a-yeoman-project

It required some updates so I have written a post about it, detailing how to `@import 'foundation'`. Here - http://calvinx.com/2013/07/11/zurb-foundation-via-gem-with-yeoman-gruntfilejs/

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you are using [grunt-contrib-compass](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass) and running compass as a grunt task.

With Foundation 5, the following don't work

- `require 'foundation'` (or 'zurb-foundation')
- using the `importPath` option to specify the location

The workaround is what I coincidentally found on the [migration page](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/upgrading.html), 
which is to specify an external config file through `config: config.rb`. In that config file, specify an import path:

`add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"`

Then when you call `grunt compass` it will compile fine

Comment: add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"  

Worked for me! Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the 'importPath' option which worked for me.

My Gruntfile.js has config like this...

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          loadPath: 'bower_components/foundation/scss'
        },
        files: {
          'public/static/css/main.css': 'app/frontend/scss/foundation.scss'
        }
      },
```

Notice the loadPath option which points to the location of my foundation components. In my foundation.scss file the imports look like:

```
@import "foundation/components/accordion"
```

So the path gets resolved to: bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/accordion

Answer (score 0):

Do not install Foundation via Bower. Bower is used to fetch assets, but Foundation is a Compass extension that should be used directly via Compass.

For `@import "foundation";` to work, you have to add `require 'foundation'` to your Compass configuration file and install Foundation via `gem install zurb-foundation`.

Comment: Not true (anymore): “With Foundation 4, we've removed all dependencies from the framework. This means you can use Foundation with Sass alone and add Compass, Bourbon, or whatever on top of it.” —[Zurb website](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html).