# Problems including foundation with grunt-contrib-compass

Tags: javascript, ruby, sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

I have trying to get foundation to work with `grunt-contrib-compass`, but to no avail.  I am using the `angular-fullstack` yo generator.  Options are directly injected into the `gruntfile`, by passing:

```
compass: {
  options: {
    force: true,
    require: 'foundation',
...
```

I followed http://ericdfields.com/post/installing-compass-frameworks-in-a-yeoman-project and [scss: compass, gruntjs and bower install foundation - import path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480443/scss-compass-gruntjs-and-bower-install-foundation-import-path).

This however returns an error:

```
    Warning: LoadError on line ["36"] of /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb: cannot load such file -- foundation
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace Use --force to continue.
```

foundation has been installed with `gem install zurb-foundation`.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add `zurb-foundation` instead of `foundation`.

```
compass: {
  options: {
    force: true,
    require: 'zurb-foundation',
...
```

And within your main.scss you can import using below line.

```
@import "foundation";
```