# Foundation scss compass, gruntjs and bower install

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation, compass-sass

Possible double with [scss: compass, gruntjs and bower install foundation - import path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480443/scss-compass-gruntjs-and-bower-install-foundation-import-path)

So i have :

```
-models
-public
    ─bower_components
     ├───fastclick
     │   └───lib
     ├───foundation
     │   ├───css
     │   ├───js
     │   │   ├───foundation
     │   │   └───vendor
     │   └───scss
     │       └───foundation
     │           └───components

Gruntfile.js
package.json
```

My gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    grunt.initConfig({
      compass: {                  // Task
        dist: {                   // Target
          options: {              // Target options
            sassDir: 'public/scss',
            cssDir: 'public/stylesheets',
            environment: 'production',
            require: 'zurb-foundation',
            importPath: 'public/bower_components/foundation/scss',
            cacheDir: 'public/.sass_cache',
          }
        }
      },

      watch: {
        css: {
            files: ['public/scss/_settings.scss'],
            tasks: ['compass:dist'],
            option: { 
                spawn: false, 
                livereload: true
            }
        }
      }
    });

}
```

When i use command : `grunt compass`

```
Running "compass:dist" (compass) task
Nothing to compile. If you're trying to start a new project, you have left off the directory argument.
Run "compass -h" to get help.

Done, without errors.
```

It doesn't work ... compass don't compile my scss... How can i correct that ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to register your tasks. Like so:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Configuration goes here
  grunt.initConfig({                  
    // blah
  });  

  // Define your tasks here
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['compass', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('justCompass', ['compass']);
};
```

Now just call `grunt` to run both compass and watch or `grunt justCompass` to run only the compass task.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to registering your tasks, you also need to read the package.json file.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json')
    // all the other code
  });
};
```